# Read object file with a .a file in linux and/or python

Tags: linux, file, .a

I need to generate a list of all functions defined in static (*.a) and dynamic libraries (*.so), for this I am only considering *.a and *.so files. This I have to do for whatever packages are installed on my machine. To do this I have to read through *.so and *.a files below (A/B) are the ways I am trying to achieve this.

For time being I am not worries about if a function is overloaded, I just need to get its name.

A) For shared library I am trying to retrieve this information by going through various option that I came across. I would appreciate if someone can point which would be the best approach.

option #1 - using `objdump`
    objdump -TC libhdf5_cpp_cray.so | grep text

Result1 - Gives a bunch of text, however function name is still hard to find

```
0000000000040b50 g    DF .text  0000000000000238  Base        H5::DSetCreatPropList::allFiltersAvail()
0000000000050320 g    DF .text  000000000000000f  Base        H5::AbstractDs::AbstractDs(H5::AbstractDs const&)
00000000000332b0 g    DF .text  0000000000000207  Base        H5::Attribute::flush(H5F_scope_t) const
000000000003e9d0 g    DF .text  0000000000000201  Base        H5::FileAccPropList::getFcloseDegree()
```

The results that I got looks like this though I am not sure how and what function names to extract

Option #2 using nm

```
nm -g libhdf5_cpp_cray.so
```

Result2 - Not sure which symbol should I pick up for function names

```
0000000000056340 T _ZNK2H59FloatType9getFieldsERmS1_S1_S1_S1_
0000000000056560 T _ZNK2H59FloatType9setFieldsEmmmmm
                 U _ZNKSs5c_strEv
00000000002732c0 V _ZTIN2H520IdComponentExceptionE
0000000000282c00 V _ZTIN2H55GroupE
```

Option #3 using readelf

```
readelf -Ws libhdf5_cpp_cray.so | grep FUNC
```

Result3 - Not sure whether I should pull the text from the column(#6 Ndx) which has UND.

```
  2099: 0000000000000000     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND H5Sget_select_npoints
  2100: 0000000000040b50   568 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   10 _ZN2H517DSetCreatPropList15allFiltersAvailEv
  2101: 0000000000050320    15 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   10 _ZN2H510AbstractDsC1ERKS0_
  2103: 00000000000332b0   519 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   10 _ZNK2H59Attribute5flushE11H5F_scope_t
  2105: 000000000003e9d0   513 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   10 _ZN2H515FileAccPropList15getFcloseDegreeEv
```

B) For all the object files (*.o) zipped in a library file (*.a), retrieve all the function names defined. For this I could only get how to read what all object files zipped together in it. Again to read through these object file and retrieve function name is something new to me would appreciate your input.

I have used ar to read in .a files

```
ar -t libhdf5_cpp.a
```

Result.b -

```
H5Exception.o
H5IdComponent.o
H5Library.o
H5Attribute.o
```

Comment: You need to tell us more about your (higher-level) requirements.  There is no single "best way" - it depends what you're doing.

Comment: However, if you're wondering about how to interpret the symbols you're encountering - they are C++ "mangled".   Check out man c++filt, for example..

Comment: Added few more details, for time being I am not worried about overloaded function I just need to get its name.